# Python Weasyprint

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

Please bear with me as i put these into words,

I am running Weasyprint on Python Django Framework, 
I have have 15 page html to render to PDF.

Rendering takes about 70% to 80% of my CPU when one user click button to render, My question is, Is there something I can use to queue users request for rendering?
Instead of processing render requests at the same time, make them wait in a queue?

Answer (score 2):

You can check `Celery`. The idea is to use asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing using a broker like `RabbitMQ` or `Redis`

http://www.celeryproject.org/

Ideally, your background task should run on servers different from the application servers so that they can scale independently and won't affect each other.

Comment: Any examples of how to do this?

Comment: @alias51You can use this article for example https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs

Answer (score -2):

**converting html to doc**

from weasyprint import HTML

```
def render_to_doc(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template  = get_template(template_src)
    HTML  =  template.render(context_dict)
    timestamp  = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    file_name  = f'promissorynote_{timestamp}.doc'
    # saving pdf in media rootfile
    pdf_path  = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'doc', file_name)
    HTML(string=html).write_pdf(pdf_path)
    return  file_name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).